# Entity framework 6 execution strategy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I am use EF6 and stored procedure which returns 2 table depending on some condition.
for convert to class we have create extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Translate<T>(this DataBase database, DbDataReader reader)
    {
        var result = ((IObjectContextAdapter) database).ObjectContext
            .Translate<T>(reader).ToList();
        reader.NextResult();
        return result;
    }
```

but in that case if class is not mach to table then also EF not throw exception 
which we wont throw exception instated he create class with null values.

calling code ex

```
 using (var db = new DataBase())
        {
        db.Database.Initialize(true);
        var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "GetStudent";
        db.Database.Connection.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            var studentList = db.Translate<Student>(reader);
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide some code which calls this? It's hard to understand the problem without seeing the calling code.

Comment: Sample code is added